# SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try ,Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am missing catch or finally after try what should I try in catch I don't understand what to add in catch. `mute.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    category: 'moderation',
    description: 'This will mute a user of your choice in this server',
    async execute(msg, args) {
    if (msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')){
        const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
    (role) => role.name === 'Muted'
    );

    if (!mutedRole)
 return message.channel.send('There is no Muted role on this server');

     target.roles.add(mutedRole);

     setTimeout(() => {
  target.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
  }, mssetTimeout()) 
        const member = msg.mentions.users.first();
            if (!member) return msg.channel.reply(`*You couldn\'t ${this.name} that member!*`);
            try {
                msg.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).ban();
                msg.channel.send(`User has been ${this.name}ed.`);
        }


        }
    } else {
        msg.reply('You do not have access to this command')
    }
      },
    };
```

Here is my error:

```
/usr/src/app/commands/mute.js:24
        }
        ^

SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/bot.js:28:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

If you think of a catch that should be added in my mute command I am an amature programmer with very bad skills in it shat is something I should add in it.

Comment: The error couldn't be more self explanatory... You can't have try without a catch block or finally. See how try and catch work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Comment: ok thank u i feel really dumb now

Comment: ok im having some trouble after i fixed this and other things i cant use the command if u could link a helpful think or just tell me what i did wrong id thank also i cant ask another question for 7 days

Comment: It would be hard to help this way. You [can't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) another question for 7 days, because your questions were poorly received. SO is giving you time to investigate why your questions were poorly received and to try to improve yourself at writing questions, that will earn you upvotes instead of downvotes. You can read everything in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also SO is advising you to edit and improve all of your poorly received questions. So you can try that, wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) (how try - catch structure looks like):

```js
try {
  // try_statements - The statements to be executed.
}
catch (exception_var) {
  // catch_statements - Statement that is executed if an exception is thrown 
  // in the try-block.
}
finally {
  // finally_statements - Statements that are executed after the try statement completes.
  // These statements execute regardless of whether an exception was thrown or caught. 
}
```

Now the important part:

> The `try` statement consists of a `try`-block, which contains one or more statements. `{}` must always be used, even for single statements. At least one `catch`-block, or a `finally`-block, must be present. This gives us three forms for the try statement:

> - `try...catch`
> - `try...finally`
> - `try...catch...finally`

You can't have a `try` block wihout a `catch` or `finally`. So in your code add one of those, even if you leave the body (`{}`) empty.